# Custom Style ListBox c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть такой стиль ListBoxItem:

```
<ListBox Margin="140,0,140,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding}">

                </Image>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding}">

                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

и вот такой стиль самого ListBox:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" Focusable="False">
                        <StackPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
                            </Setter.Value>

                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Как бы вместо

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0" Focusable="False">
    <StackPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

думаю сделать

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0" Focusable="False">
    <WrapPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Но проблема в том что он автоматические рассчитывать столько входит элементов по горизонтали и вставляет а мне надо только  4 по горизонтали
Подскажите как это реализовать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635431/specify-the-max-number-of-columns-for-a-wrappanel-in-wpf

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636396/set-max-rows-in-a-wrap-panel

Comment: В добавок к комментарию @maxwell, можно еще перегрузить метод `protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)` в данном методе считывать ширину дочерних элементов, и на основе их ширины, делать перенос, или менять их ширину до необходимого, что бы помешалось ровно 4 элемента.

Comment: А почему не просто `<UniformGrid Columns="4"/>`?